# TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions') in session in express js

Tags: node.js, express

While using session in express js, I am getting following error.

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret:'xyz'}));

TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions at EventEmitter.use (D:\lms-node\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
```

Comment: What is `session` in your example?

Comment: interesting error @alexmac

Comment: can you show us your full code?

Comment: var session = require('express-sessions');

Comment: `express-sessionS`? Maybe `express-session`?

Comment: it's all lower case isn't it ? @alexmac

Comment: @turmuka plural and single.

Comment: @alexmac  while using express-session                                       
 express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option app.js:110:9
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option app.js:110:9

Comment: Then read proper documentation how to use [express-sessionS](https://github.com/konteck/express-sessions). Your example is for `express-session`.

Comment: already read many documentation.

Comment: as soon as I comment the  app.use(session({sectret})) the code works fine

Comment: express-session worked